# My Code Searches a Tree for a Target, but is this Recursive?

Tags: ruby, recursion, tree

I am attempting to search a simple tree to find a target value. My instructions are to use recursion. I understand that recursion means (in part) that the method is called from within itself. In that sense the following code succeeds. However, I also understand (I think) that recursion requires setting up an inquiry that cannot be resolved until the base case is reached, at which time the answer is passed back in the chain and each unresolved inquiry can be resolved. My code does not really do that (I think). I need a higher power to show me (and hopefully others) the way.

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :payload, :children

  def initialize(payload, children)
    @payload = payload
    @children = children
  end

  def self.test (node, target)
    if node.payload == target
      print "Bingo!"
    else
      print node.payload
    end
    node.children.each do |child|
      Tree.test(child, target)
    end
  end
end


# The "Leafs" of a tree, elements that have no children
deep_fifth_node = Tree.new(5, [])
eleventh_node = Tree.new(11, [])
fourth_node   = Tree.new(4, [])

# The "Branches" of the tree
ninth_node = Tree.new(9, [fourth_node])
sixth_node = Tree.new(6, [deep_fifth_node, eleventh_node])
seventh_node = Tree.new(7, [sixth_node])
shallow_fifth_node = Tree.new(5, [ninth_node])

# The "Trunk" of the tree
trunk   = Tree.new(2, [seventh_node, shallow_fifth_node])

Tree.test(trunk, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your function calls itself (and yours appears to), you're using recursion. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion for a good discussion on recursion.

To prevent infinite recursion, you'll want a base case that makes sure that you do eventually unwind everything completely, rather than simply continuing to call your function forever, and quite often that is when you're fully complete with whatever computation you're running, but it doesn't necessarily mean you couldn't find what you're looking for (in the case of a search) before you reach the base case.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your function is using recursion: It calls itself.

Here is a proposal for your method:

```
  def find_nodes_with_payload?(target, result = [])
    if payload == target
      result << self
    end
    children.each do |child|
      child.find_nodes_with_payload?(target, result)
    end
    accu
  end
```

The method will collect *all* the nodes in a (sub)-tree containing a specific target value. Does solve your problem?

I modified your original code in following ways:

- Made it an instance method and removed the 'node' argument
- Renamed it from 'test' to something more descriptive, IMHO
- added an array which collects all the nodes that contain the payload
- changed the logic to: do nothing but recursively call the method again for all the children if the condition does not match

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple.

```
def search(tree, target)
  trav = ->(node) { node.val == target ? puts("Bingo") : node.leaves.each(&trav) }
  trav[tree]
end
```

Tree creation can also be simplified.

```
Node = Struct.new(:val, :leaves)
add = ->(tree) { tree ? tree.map {|k,v| Node.new(k, add[v])} : [] }
```

So we can recursively create tree and find value.

```
sample_tree = {2 => {7 => {6 => {4=>{}, 11=>{}}}, 5=> {9 => {}, 4=>{}}}}
tree = add[sample_tree]
search(tree.first, 5)
```

Comment: Nice!  Tight code like that is a little beyond my current abilities.